# MongoDB query to update dates doesn't work on all documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Basically I want to update all documents inside one collection. The update is just adding 2 hours to date fields present in each document.
The documents all follow a basic structure like this :

```json
    {
        code : 1,
        file : {
            dates : {
                start : 2018-05-27 22:00:00.000Z,
                end : 2018-05-27 22:00:00.000Z,
            },
            otherInfos : {
                ...
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my query :

```js
    var cursor = db.getCollection('files').find({});
        
    while(cursor.hasNext()){
        e = cursor.next();
        let delta = 120*60*1000; //2 hours
    
        if(e.file.dates) {
            let fileStartDate = e.file.dates.start ? new Date(e.file.dates.start.getTime() + delta) : null;
            let fileEndDate = e.file.dates.end ? new Date(e.file.dates.end.getTime() + delta) : null;
              
            if(fileStartDate) {
               e.file.dates.start = fileStartDate;
            }
            
            if(fileEndDate) {
               e.file.dates.end = fileEndDate;
            }
        }
        
        print(e);
        db.getMongo().getDB('myDB').files.updateOne(
            {"code":e.code},
            {
                $set: {"file.dates.start": fileStartDate, "file.dates.end": fileEndDate}
            })
    }
```

I am testing the query with around 20 documents and the first 10 are perfectly printed and updated with +2hours as expected but then for the second half the dates remain the exact same than before (both with the print and update).
All the documents have the same structure and same Date type so I don't understand why the query doesn't go all the way.

EDIT :
Here is a document that was succesfully updated :

```json
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b36c7fdd515e80009e7cc84"),
        "code" : "1",
        "file" : {
            "dates" : {
                "start" : ISODate("2018-06-11T22:00:00.000Z"),
                "end" : ISODate("2018-06-11T22:00:00.000Z")
            }
        }
    }
```

became as expected

```json
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b36c7fdd515e80009e7cc84"),
        "code" : "1",
        "file" : {
            "dates" : {
                "start" : ISODate("2018-06-12T00:00:00.000Z"),
                "end" : ISODate("2018-06-12T00:00:00.000Z")
            }
        }
    }
```

but for example this document :

```json
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b36c7ffd515e80009e7cf03"),
        "code" : "15",
        "file" : {
            "dates" : {
                "start" : ISODate("2018-09-02T22:00:00.000Z"),
                "end" : ISODate("2019-09-26T22:00:00.000Z")
            }
        }
    }
```

stayed the exact same

Comment: We probably need some sample of **both your working and not working** documents to try to figure out the difference

Comment: I edited my question with some sample if that can be helpfull but I doubt the problem comes from the data, I tried on various sets of documents and it always update the first ones and stops working after a few

Comment: I cannot spot the difference between the 2 documents you provided too... Nevertheless, if you are using MongoDB v4.2+,  you may consider doing your update like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nwaZmZ5-NQR)

Comment: Unfortunately I am working with MongoDB v4.2.14 and $dateAdd is only available for v5+ (https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateAdd/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With MongoDBv4.2+, you can do an update with aggregation pipeline. Use `$add` to increment 2 hour * 60 minute * 60 seconds * 1000 milliseconds.

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "file.dates.start": {
        $add: [
          "$file.dates.start",
          7200000
        ]
      },
      "file.dates.end": {
        $add: [
          "$file.dates.end",
          7200000
        ]
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Au18faoLmEF) for your reference.

Comment: This works very well, thank you ! I still don't understand the initial problem but this is the perfect workaround

Comment: @RemiFoucault To be honest, I don't know what is wrong with your method too. But the `cursor.hasNext()` is rare to me. Usually we use [forEach](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/#mongodb-method-cursor.forEach) to iterate through the query result

Answer (score 0):

```
db.getMongo().getDB('myDB').files.updateOne(
        {"code":e.code},
        {
            $set: {"file.dates.start": fileStartDate, "file.dates.end": fileEndDate}
        })
```

updateOne only allows update on one document

Comment: I also tried with an update() but the result is the same. I am trying to update each document one by one with the cursor. The first few updateOne() are working fine but it seems like past a certain point I am not anymore able to change anything to the document I get with the cursor

Comment: The current update method being used by OP could be inefficient, but it should be working since it is looping the result and update one by one. The updateOne should not be the culprit for only a subset of documents not getting update while another subset is being updated

Comment: Ah, I see. How about the e variable, does that update correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `updateMany()` to update more than 1 document
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/